# What does a well-mannered python module do to install itself?

Tags: python-import

I have a piece of python software that was written by someone else as a 1500-line single-file module, with comments at the bottom saying to insert source code there that invokes the classes in the module. I would like to improve this, and hopefully do it in a nice, standard way so that my changes would be acceptable to the code's maintainters as a patch, and useful to other people.

If I do

```
python2 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

it looks like my linux installation of python expects modules to be in /usr/lib/python2.7 or /usr/lib/python3.5. So the most basic thing that occurs to me is to write a Makefile with an "install" target that detects the version numbers 2.7 and 3.5, and copies the module to the appropriate spots.

I'm guessing this is not the best or most standard way to do this, since for one thing it won't work on Windows. Should I instead be setting it up using pip somehow? The examples I've seen of how to use pip all seem to assume that you're using code that someone else has written and that has already been accepted into some central repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pip. Make a setup.py file with something like:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['mypackage'],
    license='Some license',
    long_description='Insert description'
)
```

This assumes that your file structure is something like this:

```
mypackage/
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        myfile.py
    setup.py
```

Then run `pip install -e .` (development install) or just `pip install .` (normal install) in the package directory.
The difference between these is that `pip install -e` does not copy it to the python directory and just links it there, which I guess you don't want.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a reasonable answer, +1. Unfortunately I spent about an hour trying to get this to work and ended up giving up. Ran into lots of problems such as python2/3 incompatibilities, bugs in pip (updating pip erases the pip3 executable), commands failing without error messages, commands failing with uninformative error messages.